# Filepond: several instances leads to having several submit.php's, which doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, upload, filepond

I'm trying to make several instances of filepond on the same page, that should lead to different upload directories. I'm using the following code that was suggested on the github page:

```
$('.pond1').filepond({ allowMultiple: true, server: 'my-first-url' });
$('.pond2').filepond({ allowMultiple: true, server: 'my-second-url' });
```

However, having several servers means each server comes with it's own submit.php. But one form can only have one submit button, right? As a result, my files are correctly being uploaded to the tmp directory, but upon submit, nothing more happens.

Am I doing something wrong?

Cheers!